# Problems deleting video from document directory

Tags: ios, video, nsdocumentdirectory

I am trying to delete a video from the document directory, but the video isn't deleting.

Here is how I am trying to delete the video:

```
//Delete Video
NSError *error = nil;
//NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.finalURL];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: tempPath error: &error];
UIAlertView *removeSuccessFulAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[removeSuccessFulAlert show];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might get a good hint at your problem if you put in a line after your "`removeItemAtPath`" that says something like:

```
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: tempPath error: &error];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"error from removing item at path %@ is %@", 
        tempPath, [error localizedDescription]);   
} else {
    UIAlertView *removeSuccessFulAlert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Congratulation:" message:@"Successfully removed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" otherButtonTitles:nil];
   [removeSuccessFulAlert show];
}
```

Comment: Ok, so this logs `error from removing item at path /var/mobile/Applications/E5532C71-82BD-4348-AB5E-002A14C975B3/Documents/vid1.mp4 is The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4.)`

Comment: @matthew are you sure the movie file exists?

Comment: So I have fixed that error. The only problem is that when I delete the video, the amount of space the app takes up drops, but not all the way to where it was before the video was taken. So it starts out at 18, then when a video is taken, it goes to 56, but when deleted it only goes down to like 20, not all the way back to 18.

Comment: I think that error was just something weird happening because it only   occurred that one time.

Comment: @matthew normally Cocoa error 4 means the file doesn't exist.

Comment: So I have fixed that error, I was just wondering about the deletion still leaving a little data behind

Comment: what does that "leaving a little data behind" mean, @Matthew??  Is this a different / new question?

Comment: So look at the third comment on your answer

Comment: what else is being written out into files besides that one .mp4 file?

Comment: So I am also saving the url and a thumbnail image to core data. It looks like it is deleting the video and url but something weird is happening with the image. When I press delete, the image disappears from the table like it is deleted but if I restart the app, the image appear again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"vid1.mp4"];
```

Comment: +1 to you for the correct way to append a plain NSString onto the end of a path, but I'm pretty certain the "`stringByAppendingFormat`" with zero format arguments isn't the problem.