# Deleting from document directory only deleting half of saved data

Tags: ios, video, nsdocumentdirectory

I am saving a video to the document directory. When I take a video with the app, the amount of space the app takes up goes up, but then when I delete the video from the document directory, the amount of space the app takes up only goes down half way. For example the app takes up 1.2MB and when I take a video, it goes to 20MB. If I delete the video, the app only goes down to 10MB, not all the way back to 1.2MB as it should.

Here is the code I am using to save the video:

```
NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.videoURL];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];

BOOL success = [videoData writeToFile:tempPath atomically:NO];
```

And here is the code I am using to delete the video:

```
//Delete Video
NSError *error2 = nil;
//NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.finalURL];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *tempPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingFormat:@"/vid1.mp4"];
BOOL success = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath: tempPath error: &error2];
if(!success)
{
    NSLog(@"error from removing item at path %@ is %@",
          tempPath, [error2 localizedDescription]);
    abort();
} else {
    NSLog(@"Video deleted");

}
```

Comment: Have you scanned the app sandbox to what other files there are? Maybe there are some temp files being created.

Comment: That's the same thing I asked Matthew when he was complaining about the "size of his app" not going down in [a different question he asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21322562/problems-deleting-video-from-document-directory).

Comment: Sorry about creating another question, I figured that because it definitely is deleting part of the data being saved, it is a different question than the one before. In this case, I don't think the problem is the video not being deleted, but more the video being saved twice or something like that. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: naw, it's perfectly cool to create a new question for a brand new problem.  And @rmaddy has the right idea that there may be other files written out.  Are you using CoreData, b.t.w.?

Comment: You should remove file form temp folder as well.

Comment: So after looking at the sandbox, every time I take a video, a new file is created in the tmp folder, but when I delete the video, the file doesn't get deleted from the tmp folder. @rmaddy

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I added a comment above about what is going on in the sandbox

Comment: Then the solution is obvious. When you delete a video, also delete the associated file from the `tmp` folder.

Comment: How would I do this? @rmaddy

Comment: Didn't you just say you found a matching file in the `tmp` folder? Get reference to to the file in the `tmp` folder and delete it just like you delete the file in the `Documents` folder.

Comment: I was also wondering why it is saving to tmp because it would be better if it just saved to the document directory and nothing else @rmaddy

Comment: @Bhumeshwerkatre why is it saving it to the temp folder?

Comment: @matthew Exactly I too don't know why its saved in `tmp` folder. you can refer this link to get some info about file sytem https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html